# How to create a batch file to delete sub folders and keep files?

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have a folder on my Windows system with the following contents:

```
c:\folder\folder1
c:\folder\folder2
c:\folder\folder3
c:\folder\folder4
c:\folder\folder5
c:\folder\folder6
c:\folder\A.bat
c:\folder\b.bat
```

I want to run a batch file that leaves only

```
c:\folder\A.bat
c:\folder\b.bat
```

and deletes the rest. I.e., delete all sub-folders, irrespective of whether they contain files themselves, and retain only the "top level" files.

How can I do this?

Comment: So you want to delete all sub-folders, irrespective of whether they contain files themselves, and retain only the "top level" files? If this is a one-time thing it can be done far more easily via Explorer itself.

Answer (score 3):

Navigate to `C:\folder` and run the following command:

```
for /f "delims=" %d in ('dir /ad /b') do @rd /q /s "%d"
```

This will get rid of all sub-directories under `C:\folder` and leave only the files. If you want to use it in a batch file, use %% instead of %.

Comment: Since you're new here, remember to accept the answers that helped you solve your problem.